# I now that we need to put a f after a number, when we say that is a float, but why java need it, when we say that the datatype is float?

Tags: java

On this forum a lot of people said, that when we make for example:

float a=1.0; and not float a=1.0f;

that the compiler is thinking that 1.0 is a double. But why is that possible?

Float has only 32bits, a double number has 64bit!

So when we say without a f the compiler says that is a double it is not logical because the float variable has not enough space for the double, you now what I mean?

That is not logical or?

Comment: Because the Java Language Specification says that a floating-point number literal is by default interpreted as a `double`, not a `float`. In other words, `0.0` is the same as writing `0.0d`.

Comment: Java defines double is the "default type" of an unspecified floating-point literal

Comment: I now but my program compiles when I make float test=1;, when now really java interpreted this as a double, that make not sense, because a float cannot have a double in his available space

Comment: Writing `float f = 1;` is not the same thing as `float f = 1.0;`, because `1` is an `int`, not a `double`.

Comment: Oh you are right That was my problem, I dont tried it with ja float number hahahahaha, and java saw it as a int and said automatically it is correct, beaucse of auto cast

Comment: Side note about, *"On this forum..."* -- this is not and has never been a forum